# Get value between html tag when using .data() in jquery

Tags: jquery

How to get the value among the  &  if using data()?

example code:

```
<span data-name="username"> James</span>
```

i can get the value of data-name by using : `$("span:visible").data("name"); // OUTPUT : username`
but i want to get the value "James", i tried add .text() & .val() at the end, but it is not working.

Thanks.
Jack

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an [Attribute Equals](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) selector to match the element, and the [text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/) method to obtain its inner text content:

```
var spanText = $("span[data-name='username']:visible").text();
```

If the space character before `James` is significant, and you do not want it to be present in the value you fetch, you can apply [$.trim()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/):

```
var trimmedSpanText = $.trim($("span[data-name='username']:visible").text());
```

Answer (score 0):

To get "James", use

```
$('span:visible[data-name="username"]').text().trim();
```

Answer (score 0):

An other way to do this:

```
$("span:visible").html()
```

Answer (score 0):

It would work if you use:

```
$('span').text();
```

When you use this

```
$("span:visible").data("name")
```

the control gets over to the data() and so the element is not understood by the javascript as to where the text() is to be extracted from.

Answer (score 0):

```
<span id="spanTestData" data-name="username"> James</span>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.trim($('#spanTestData').text());
});
```

//================================Or ==============//

```
<span data-name="username"> James</span>

$(document).ready(function () {
    $.trim($('span[data-name]:first').text());
});
```

//================================Or ==============//

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nanoquantumtech/wZVA9/)

```
<span data-name="username"> James</span>

<span id="spanTestData" data-name="username"> James 2</span>

<h1 style="font-size:larger; font-weight:bolder;"></h1>


 $(document).ready(function () {
        $('h1').text($.trim($('span[data-name]:first').text()) + ' ||| ' + $.trim($('#spanTestData').text()));
    });
```

Comment: you should use $(document).ready(function () { }); this is used to fire jquery after page is loaded

Comment: if <span data-name="username"></span> html tags are multiple it will tack first html tag matched to the selector. so that use attribute id, you can get the value.

Comment: <span data-username="James"> James</span> $('#spanTestData').data('username');